# Writing cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, linux, android-securityexception

I am attempting to set the min/max clock speeds on a rooted phone programmatically. Following on from a suggestion made in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892198/setting-the-min-max-cpu-clock-rate-programmatically), I found [some documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1716807/how-to-change-frequency-on-linux-pub.txt) which suggests that I write the data to:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

and

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
```

I already have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in my manifest. Also I can successfully *read* both files. When I tried to write to the files, I got `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. So I tried...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"chmod 777 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*\"");
```

...which executed without error, but this made no difference. The error occurs when I execute the second of these two lines:

```
File file = new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

I'm not sure what I can try next.

**EDIT:** Following mrPjer's advice, I ran adb shell. I typed `su` and the navigated to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`. I then typed

`chmod 777 scaling_max_freq`

and confirmed that the permissions had been accepted by typing

`ls -l scaling_max_freq`

and sure enough it was listed as `-rwxrwxrwx`. I then typed

`echo 124200 > scaling_max_freq`

and then

`cat scaling_max_freq`

sadly this reported that the file was unchanged as "1512000".

**EDIT:** This question has now drifted away somewhat from the original title, so I'm going to post the last edit as [a new question altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933159/scaling-max-freq-resists-being-altered-despite-write-permission-and-a-rooted-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the permissions on the system files to globally readable / writable (which you really shouldn't do), try writing the files directly using root access.

You can easily do this by using echo instead of chmod in your su call. E.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"echo 1234 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq\"");
```

The exec call should also return a Process object on which you can call waitFor() which will give you the return code of the call. If that is any different than zero, something went wrong.

Finally, confirm that you actually do get root access - when executing the su request, does a dialog pop up asking you to allow the action?

Also, since you are writing root enabled apps, take a look at the RootTools library: https://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage.

Comment: Sounds like good advice. I tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"echo 594000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq\""); and that executed without throwing any exceptions... but sadly when I read the file moments later to check it had worked, it was "384000". Maybe your answer gives the correct way to write the file, but somehow it is not enough to permanently set the min cpu speed :-(

Comment: The phone is rooted (100% sure). Whether that automatically means my app has root access or not I am less certain.

Comment: Can you confirm that the app has root access?

Also, can you confirm the return code you get from executing that command?

It's been a while since I did someting similar, but do check if you need to do anything extra if your CPU has multiple cores.

Also, to make debugging easier, I'd suggest you first try getting a command that works by using adb shell. This will give you a standard shell in which you can try out commands which you can later put in the exec() call.

Comment: I can't see how to get a return code from "exec()". With regard "check if you need to do anything extra if your CPU has multiple cores" - I have no idea how to find out. I have been looking in lots of places with no luck. I will play with adb shell.

Comment: I can't test this now, but the return type of the exec call should be a Process object. Let's say you assign it with Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...). You can get the return code from that process object by calling int returnCode = p.waitFor();. Check if that is different than 0. Also, when running things in the ADB shell, you can check the return code of the last command by running echo $?. Also, the cpuinfo_min_freq file might be read only. See if you have the scaling_min_freq in the same directory.

Comment: Confirm you can actually run both su and echo with adb shell. Depending on how your system is set up, you may have to provide the full path to the binaries (something along /system/xbin/su). However, this won't work on all devices. For a more robust way, check out http://su.chainfire.eu/.

Comment: See edit to OP. Bothe echo and su appear to execute without error even when I'm in the cpufreq directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64889/discussion-between-mrpjer-and-mick).

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error as root, you may want to try the following command:

```
cpufreq-set -c 0 --max 124200
```

As well you can specify different cores with the -c, and governors with -g