# scaling_max_freq resists being altered despite write permission

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to change the value stored `in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` which is currently set to "1512000". I am attempting to do this via adb shell.

I type su and then navigate to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq. I then type

```
chmod 777 scaling_max_freq
```

I confirm that the chmod worked by typing

```
ls -l scaling_max_freq
```

and sure enough it is listed as -rwxrwxrwx. I then type

```
echo 124200 > scaling_max_freq
```

and then

```
cat scaling_max_freq
```

sadly this reports that the file is unchanged as "1512000". None of the lines executed responded with any kind of error.

Maybe the governor is immediately overwriting this? Maybe I need some extra type of permission? Maybe this is somehow fundamentally not allowed on an android device and I need to control the clock speeds via a different mechanism altogether? The problem must be soluable somehow as it it performed by [SetCPU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhuang.overclocking&hl=en_GB).

BTW, this was all on a rooted Sony xperia z, Android 4.4.2, build number 10.5.A.0.230

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggested attempting to write to scaling_min_freq... I tried it and to my surprise it worked. I was even more surprised when, afterwards I set scaling_max_freq and that worked too. I found this amazing because [this document](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuning_cpufreq_policy_and_speed.html) suggests that if anything you should set them in the reverse order.

Anyway, it all seems to be working now.